# How can I get a player head that can only be placed on a specific block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I Have a adventure map and I want to know how to get a head that can only be placed on a certain block. I know how to make blocks that can only be placed on certain blocks, but I want a head that can be placed on a certain block and I want the head to be a TNT head, like so:

```
/give Angel_Scarz minecraft:skull 1 3 {SkullOwner:"MHF_Tnt"}
```

How can I make it so that this head can only be placed on a certain block?

Comment: Thanks but it did not work..

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
/give <player> minecraft:skull 1 3 {SkullOwner:"MHF_Tnt",CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:<block_id>","minecraft:<block_id2>]}
```

replacing the values inside the `<>` with what you want